# My client freezes when I call the WCF CallBack

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, callback

I am calling WCF Callback service which is returning a List. Actually when I click on login button I am checking the Username and Password. If correct, the method will fetch the List and return it to the client.

Now, if I give the wrong username or wrong password the message is displayed "Invalid Username/Password.". But, when I try to give the credentials again, it freezes. It doesn't call the method again.

I don't know where the problem lies. I enable tracing as well, but the second time it does not call the method so there is nothing in the tracing file.

Thanks for the help.

I am calling the service like this:

```
 InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(this);
 LoginClient client = new LoginClient(context);
List<UserEN> result = client.Login(userLogin, ref message).ToList<UserEN>();
```

My Service Contract:

```
 [ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(ISaadiqinCallback))]
    public interface ILogin
    {
        [OperationContract]
        List<UserEN> Login(UserEN _user, ref string message);
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ISaadiqinCallback
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void BroadcastToClient(List<UserEN> authorizationList);

        [OperationContract]
        void NotifyUser(string message);
    }
```

Implementation:

```
 public List<UserEN> Login(UserEN _user, ref string message)
            {
                List<UserEN> authorizationList = new List<UserEN>();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_user._userName))
                {
                    try
                    { 
                       // string message = string.Empty;
                        lock (locker)
                        {
                            callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ISaadiqinCallback>();
                            //remove the old client
                            if (clients.Keys.Contains(_user._userName))
                                clients.Remove(_user._userName);
                            //Adding the clients with userName and callback channel
                            clients.Add(_user._userName, callback);
                            //Get the authorization list from database
                           authorizationList =  new LoginBal().Login(_user, ref message);

                            }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return authorizationList;
            }
```

Comment: It sounds like the client callback channel is faulted on the second call. Can you post the code pls?

Comment: posted the code. I don't know where am i wrong.

Comment: @Rehaan Have you found a solution? I'm having a similar problem